# Counting number of occurrences with same ID before date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of events with IDs and dates. What I want to know is the number of events that have occurred with that id in the past. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=10, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 'date':rng})
```

The input dataframe:

```
    date       id
0   2018-01-01  1
1   2018-01-02  1
2   2018-01-03  1
3   2018-01-04  2
4   2018-01-05  2
5   2018-01-06  3
6   2018-01-07  3
7   2018-01-08  3
8   2018-01-09  3
9   2018-01-10  3
```

Desired output:

```
    date       id   occurrences
0   2018-01-01  1   0
1   2018-01-02  1   1
2   2018-01-03  1   2
3   2018-01-04  2   0
4   2018-01-05  2   1
5   2018-01-06  3   0
6   2018-01-07  3   1
7   2018-01-08  3   2
8   2018-01-09  3   3
9   2018-01-10  3   4
```

This is easy to do by looping through the rows, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it. Here is the solution just by looping through the rows:

```
occurrences = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    occurrences.append(df[(df['id'] == row['id']) & (df['date'] < row['date'])].shape[0])

df['occurrences'] = occurrences
```

Comment: Have you tried grouping by `id` sorting by `date` then cumsum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

groupby `id` and `cumcount`:

```
df.groupby('id').cumcount()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    0
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    4
```

---

**Note**
Affect to your df:

```
df['occurences'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
```

Or (As @Scott said)
Use assign to get the following one-liner:

```
df.assign(occurences = df.groupby('id').cumcount())
```

Result

```
print(df)
        date  id  occurences
0 2018-01-01   1           0
1 2018-01-02   1           1
2 2018-01-03   1           2
3 2018-01-04   2           0
4 2018-01-05   2           1
5 2018-01-06   3           0
6 2018-01-07   3           1
7 2018-01-08   3           2
8 2018-01-09   3           3
9 2018-01-10   3           4
```

Comment: `df.assign(occurences = df.groupby('id').cumcount())` one-liner.

Comment: Can do `df['occurences'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()`. That's a one liner too.